# How to find out the number of unique elements for a column in a group in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe-

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("u1", 1),
    ("u1", 2),
    ("u2", 1),
    ("u2", 1),
    ("u2", 1),
    ("u3", 3),
    ],
    ['user_id', 'var1'])

print(df1.printSchema())
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Output-

```
root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- var1: long (nullable = true)

None
+-------+----+
|user_id|var1|
+-------+----+
|u1     |1   |
|u1     |2   |
|u2     |1   |
|u2     |1   |
|u2     |1   |
|u3     |3   |
+-------+----+
```

Now I want to group all the unique users and show the number of unique var for them in a new column. The desired output would look like-

```
+-------+---------------+
|user_id|num_unique_var1|
+-------+---------------+
|u1     |2              |
|u2     |1              |
|u3     |1              |
+-------+---------------+
```

I can use collect_set and make a udf to find the set's length. But I think there must be a better way to do it.
How do I achieve this in one line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df1.groupBy('user_id').agg(F.countDistinct('var1').alias('num')).show()
```

**countDistinct** is exactly what I needed.

Output-

```
+-------+---+
|user_id|num|
+-------+---+
|     u3|  1|
|     u2|  1|
|     u1|  2|
+-------+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

`countDistinct` is surely the best way to do it, but for the sake of completeness, what you said in your question is also possible without using an UDF. You can use `size` to get the length of the `collect_set`:

```
df1.groupBy('user_id').agg(F.size(F.collect_set('var1')).alias('num'))
```

this is helpful if you want to use it in a window function, because `countDistinct` is not supported in a window function.

e.g.

```
df1.withColumn('num', F.countDistinct('var1').over(Window.partitionBy('user_id')))
```

would fail, but

```
df1.withColumn('num', F.size(F.collect_set('var1')).over(Window.partitionBy('user_id')))
```

would work.

Comment: i had tried F.len instead of F.size and it did not work. Thanks for the new info

Comment: @n0obcoder there is no such thing as F.len. You can see all the available functions in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions) (there's a LOT!)

Comment: in fact there's a F.length, but that's used for measuring the length of a string.